# Is there a way to combine a value with a row easily with pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My Dataframe in Python using pandas looks like this:

```
Country | Year | January | February | ...| December
Angola | 2016 | 1 | 2 | ... | 3
Angola | 2017 | 4 | 5 | ... | 6
Angola | 2018 | 7 | 8 | ... | 9
Burundi | 2016 | 10 | 11 | ... | 12
```

and I want it to modify to this:

```
Country | Date | value
Angola | 01.2016 | 1
Angola | 02.2016 | 2
...
Angola | 12.2016 | 3
Angola | 01.2017 | 4
Angola | 02.2017 | 5
...
Angola | 12.2017 | 6
Angola | 01.2018 | 7
Angola | 02.2018 | 8
...
Angola | 12.2018 | 9
Burundi | 01.2016 | 10
Burundi | 02.2016 | 11
...
Burundi | 12.2016 | 12
```

I was wondering if there is a function for this in pandas?

Comment: Hi and welcome on SO. It will be great if you can have a look at [how-to-ask](/help/how-to-ask) and then try to produce a [mcve](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) for unpivot with convert combinations of `Year` extracted by [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) with [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html), then sorting by both columns by [`DataFrame.sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and last for custom strings of datetimes use [`Series.dt.strftime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html):

```
df = df.melt(id_vars=['Country','Year'], var_name='Date')
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.pop('Year').astype(str) + df['Date'], format='%Y%B')
df = df.sort_values(['Country','Date'], ignore_index=True)
df['Date'] = df['Date'].dt.strftime('%m.%Y')
print (df)
    Country     Date  value
0    Angola  01.2016      1
1    Angola  02.2016      2
2    Angola  12.2016      3
3    Angola  01.2017      4
4    Angola  02.2017      5
5    Angola  12.2017      6
6    Angola  01.2018      7
7    Angola  02.2018      8
8    Angola  12.2018      9
9   Burundi  01.2016     10
10  Burundi  02.2016     11
11  Burundi  12.2016     12
```

Or alternative solution with [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html), then sorting is not necessary:

```
df1 = (df.rename_axis('Date', axis=1)
         .set_index(['Country','Year'])
         .stack()
         .reset_index(name='value'))
df1['Date'] = (pd.to_datetime(df1.pop('Year').astype(str) + df1['Date'], format='%Y%B')
                 .dt.strftime('%m.%Y'))
print (df1)
    Country     Date  value
0    Angola  01.2016      1
1    Angola  02.2016      2
2    Angola  12.2016      3
3    Angola  01.2017      4
4    Angola  02.2017      5
5    Angola  12.2017      6
6    Angola  01.2018      7
7    Angola  02.2018      8
8    Angola  12.2018      9
9   Burundi  01.2016     10
10  Burundi  02.2016     11
11  Burundi  12.2016     12
```